# Bash tool to search for regex pattern in file

Tags: linux, bash

I want a bash tool that does the following: Given a file and a regex pattern, it outputs all matches of that pattern in the file.

Any tool like that? Grep or something? (I don't know how to use it to make that.)

Comment: You could simply use piping for that. 
Cat filename.txt | grep <pattern>

Comment: Grep is a good choice.  `man grep` to view greps documentaiton would be a good start.  It'll show you how to use it.

Comment: That is exactly what `grep` is there for. Read the man page, it explains everything. Or just try it: `grep "XXX-[0-9]+" numberfile.text`. Next try around with some of the flags, like `-n` and `-r`...

Comment: @feaDawn We're trying to reduce the UUOC factor around here, not increase it. `grep <pattern> filename.txt` would be sufficient. Leave the cats out of it...

Comment: real suggestion - google for such kind of questions

Comment: @twalberg I agree. Thanks for pointing it out. I was not aware of grep being able to handle files directly and was therefore trying to show the usage of pipes in combination with grep.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `grep`.  There are 2 ways I like to use it

```
cat file.txt | grep 'regex_pattern'
```

and

```
grep 'regex_pattern' file.txt
```

Comment: Well copied from the comments above :-)

Comment: Then why did you additionally add this answer? It is still copying, even if you copy from yourself.

Comment: To answer the question

Comment: Please don't encourage piping `cat` into `grep`, there's absolutely no need.

Comment: Nice. But what if I don't want it to be limited by line? What if I want it to search for all occurrences of the regex regardless of lines?

Comment: By default it will select all lines that match that pattern.  If you use `-o` it show only the matched part of the line.  If you do that I recommend adding `-n` which adds the line number so you know where it's at.

Comment: Ding did not copy. Actually most of the comments on the first post were added after Ding's answer. Come one guys, we're an amazing community and I'm sure we can do better than accusing each other of copying after providing a correct answer.

Comment: @RamRachum What do you mean by "all occurrences of the regex regardless of lines"? `grep` will (without additional options, some of which @Ding mentions) print every line that contains a segment within it that matches the regex. Are you perhaps trying to indicate that you want to match a multi-line regex - one that starts on one line and ends on a different one?